# Oxford C compiler for Commodore 64

Tags: commodore-64, c, compilers, identify-this-software

I kept one floppy from my Commodore 128 (which I used mostly in C64 mode), labelled ‘Oxford C compiler’. It is a 5.25″ floppy. Don't ask me why I kept just this one; probably because I thought I wanted not to keep a game but something ‘serious’. I think it even doesn't work anymore (nor I can play it back since I don't own a Commodore anymore).

However, I cannot remember I ever used C, and most of all, I cannot find any references of an Oxford C compiler. The only reference I find is an Oxford Pascal compiler (like [here](https://www.lyonlabs.org/commodore/onrequest/collections.html)).

Was there ever an Oxford C compiler, or was it for a different computer somehow, or maybe I labelled it wrongly (and it should be Oxford Pascal); note the label is handwritten, so it's not an official disk.

I'm just a bit curious.

Comment: Can you find out what's actually on the disk? Starting the program or at least getting the filename might help in identifying the program.

Comment: Is the label torn? Maybe it originally said "Oxford Basic Compiler" meaning PetSpeed64.

Comment: @PeterB. That's the problem, I don't have a Commodore anymore, neither a 1541 drive

Comment: @snips-n-snails The label is hand written (by me though), but I must have the disk for about 35 years or more

Comment: Are you sure you understood the difference between C and Pascal 35 years ago?

Comment: @TomasBy that's also a good question... I never used the programming language at that age (13) ... I started Basic, and as far as I remember I started programming on C on the Commodore Amiga (I forgot which program I used for that but it couldn't have been Oxford C) ... I think I just wrote the label wrong, and Oxford Pascal is on this disk.

Comment: Is it possible there were Oxford A, Oxford B, ... floppies?  The only other compiler ref for Oxford I can find for the Commodore series was a BASIC compiler (mostly targeted at the PET series...)

Comment: Find your local retro computer club, ask them if they have a 1541 and/or Kryptoflux etc., and have them have a look at the floppy?

Comment: Even searching on Internet Archive only turns up ads for Oxford Pascal, so I think it's mislabeled somehow.

Comment: @dirkt Sorry for my late answer … yes I should try, but it seems to be Oxford Pascal.

Comment: @Joe I'm sure it was meant for the Commodore 64, since I never had a PET series.

Comment: @AlanB Indeed, I think it must have been mislabeled (and high likely by myself).

Comment: Oxford sold cross-compilers that targeted the C64, but they compiled BASIC, not C. Or maybe they were working on a C compiler and you have the only known preproduction copy.

Comment: @snips-n-snails I doubt it is some special disk, I probably copied it one time,so maybe it's a basic compiler., or pascal (as some others above say).

Comment: @dirkt FYI it's Kryoflux, not Kryptoflux. I checked in case the name had changed in the interval since I bought mine, but it hasn't.